# Fancybox, Custom Open Transition

Tags: jquery, fancybox, modal-dialog

Does anyone know how you open a fancyBox with a custom open transition:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Im looking to achieve a similar transition to the example found here:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

I love the reveal plugin but its not got a few of the features I require that fancyBox does for a new project

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Why not just use the plugin in the link you gave us? It even has instructions how to code it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox can have the same opening effect as in the sample you provided but not the same closing effect though.

To achieve the same opening effect, try this option:

```
openMethod : 'changeIn'
```

to keep the same effect during transition between galleries, try this option:

```
nextMethod: 'changeIn'
```

.

Answer (score 9):

Add custom transitions -

```
(function ($, F) {
    F.transitions.dropIn = function() {
        var endPos = F._getPosition(true);

        endPos.top = (parseInt(endPos.top, 10) - 200) + 'px';

        F.wrap.css(endPos).show().animate({
            top: '+=200px'
        }, {
            duration: F.current.openSpeed,
            complete: F._afterZoomIn
        });
    };

    F.transitions.dropOut = function() {
        F.wrap.removeClass('fancybox-opened').animate({
            top: '-=200px'
        }, {
            duration: F.current.closeSpeed,
            complete: F._afterZoomOut
        });
    };

}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));
```

Use them like -

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openMethod : 'dropIn',
    openSpeed : 250,

    closeMethod : 'dropOut',
    closeSpeed : 100
});
```

And whoa-la - the same effect!

Comment: This looks just right, although im getting js errors when trying to set it up, ive not extended jQuery plugins before, where is the best place to put this code? (For ref the error im getting is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitions' of undefined)

Comment: You can set the function just after the opening <script> tag and before the $(document).ready() ... then just add the options as indicated by Janis (second code segment) within your custom script.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this is I thought and tried, issue is im getting the js error mentioned above?

Comment: Add that snippet after including fancybox.js

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this now, I've written a jQuery Fancybox plugin that includes the transitions Janis (Fancybox's author) wrote to answer this question, as well as a few others, and it hopefully will continue to evolve.

See here: [jquery.fancybox.transitions.js](https://github.com/mdenton8/fancybox-transitions)

Include the javascript file in a script tag after jQuery and Fancybox

```
<script src="path to jquery"></script>
<script src="path to fancybox"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancyboxbox.transitions.js"></script>
```

More information in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

Well my advice is that unless you know how code one yourself from JQuery then you're best bet is to keep looking around the net until you can settle for something.

If you are looking at maybe remaking or extending one of these plugins then a good book to read is JQuery: Novice to Ninja, check it out on Amazon. There are lots of good tips and tricks in there.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Novice-Ninja-Earle-Castledine/dp/0980576857/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322832342&sr=8-1

Generally though you wouldn't want to re-invent the wheel.
So heres a couple of links to JQuery Lightbox plugins

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/30-efficient-jquery-lightbox-plugins/
http://webdesign14.com/30-best-jquery-lightbox-plugins/