# Change Fancybox animation type from fade in to slide up

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to tweak Fancybox to, instead of fading in from the center of the screen, sliding up from the bottom of the page?

I'm using Fancybox to load various .html pages, and I've modified it to be 100% width and 100% height of the window.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
            padding : 0,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none',
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            afterLoad  : function () {
                $.extend(this, {
                    aspectRatio : false,
                    width   : '100%',
                    height  : '100%',

                });
            }
         });
```

Comment: if you include the jQuery easing plugin, you could set a new transition effect. You may need to set `openEffect: "elastic"` and `openEasing` to any of the easing options from the easing plugin.

Comment: @JFK, I am using both elastic as my openEffect, and the easing plugin. I think the problem is that using elastic, the lightbox grows from the center of the screen, not sliding up from below. I think what I need to figure out is how to have the initial position of the lightbox be set to width: 100%, height: 100vh, position: absolute, and bottom: -100vh.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8374724/1055987 I guess this is what you need

Comment: @JFK Perfect! Took some tweaking, but I got it to do what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox, Custom Open Transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356669/fancybox-custom-open-transition)